# How can I programmatically move to center EditText?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

How can I programmatically move the **Password** to the **center** using `.AddRule (RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);`?

[image]

```
LinearLayout PO = (LinearLayout)RV .findViewById(R.id.LL1);

                EditText ET = new EditText(getActivity());
                ET.setId(1);
                ET.setHint("Your name");
                ET.setInputType(0x00000061);
                ET.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                ET.setPadding(40,20,40,20);
                ET.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                //ET.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                PO.addView(ET);
```

`.addRule` lit.

Comment: What's the problem? You already say exactly which method you want to use.

Comment: Your Eidt text is already centered horizontally and vertically already. What is the problem?

Comment: Want to move to the center of **Password** by any means, only with the programmicaly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before doing that programmatically you'd better try to build your UI in the layout.xml and only then do that things programmatically.

There should be relative layout in your layout.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
...
```

Your edittext should be inside relative layout in order to apply RelativeLayout.LayoutParams to it. And your code will look like that:

```
RelativeLayout PO = (RelativeLayout)RV .findViewById(R.id.RL1);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
          ((int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
ET.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Also you may found helpful the last answer in the following link:
http://www.coderanch.com/t/505316/Android/Mobile/put-layout-middle-screen

Answer (score 0):

You can use the gravity attribute, but this is useless if you want to add more components in your view. You can also use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout (you need to change your layout), which helps you doing things like that.

Comment: How? Show me an example, please.

Answer (score 0):

XML:

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/xxx"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
```

or in Code:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```

or

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
      ((int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
xyzView.setLayoutParams(params);
```